# jq: Multiply values from array with constants and add result to objects with matching id in another file

Tags: json, bash, jq

So there are three .json files in my directory. I have created the first file dynamically (Using linux bash and jq) which contains one object including the array "RATIO":

- ratio.json:

  ```
  [
   {...,"RATIO":[0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9], ....}
  ]
  ```

In the second file I have stored the constants (this is just hardcoded so the constants could also be moved into the code directly, if that's easier):

- constants.json:

  ```
  [
   {"ID":"aaa","CONST":250},
   {"ID":"bbb","CONST":350},
   {"ID":"ccc","CONST":200},
   {"ID":"ddd","CONST":190}
  ]
  ```

The third file is where "the magic" should happen:

- data.json:

  ```
  [
   {"ID":"aaa","time_CET":"00:00:00"},
   {"ID":"aaa","time_CET":"00:15:00"},
   {"ID":"aaa","time_CET":"00:30:00"},
   {"ID":"aaa","time_CET":"00:45:00"},

   {"ID":"bbb","time_CET":"00:00:00"},
   {"ID":"bbb","time_CET":"00:15:00"},
   {"ID":"bbb","time_CET":"00:30:00"},
   {"ID":"bbb","time_CET":"00:45:00"},

   {"ID":"ccc","time_CET":"00:00:00"},
   {"ID":"ccc","time_CET":"00:15:00"},
   {"ID":"ccc","time_CET":"00:30:00"},
   {"ID":"ccc","time_CET":"00:45:00"},

   {"ID":"ddd","time_CET":"00:00:00"},
   {"ID":"ddd","time_CET":"00:15:00"},
   {"ID":"ddd","time_CET":"00:30:00"},
   {"ID":"ddd","time_CET":"00:45:00"}
  ]
  ```

  All objects in this array should be extended by the element "VAL" which is calculated by multiplying RATIO with CONST. So in my case RATIO[0] (that's 0.5) is used for every object with time_CET = "00:00:00". RATIO[1] is used for time_CET=00:15:00 and so on. The array in data.json is already sorted as you can see (00:00:00 always first for every ID), that's why I think the trick with the array index should work.
  So in the end, the data.json file should look like this (on the right is the calculation logic for VAL):
- data.json:

  ```
  [     

    {"ID":"aaa","time_CET":"00:00:00", "VAL": 125}, ->0.5*250
    {"ID":"aaa","time_CET":"00:15:00", "VAL": 175}, ->0.7*250
    {"ID":"aaa","time_CET":"00:30:00", "VAL": 200}, ->0.8*250
    {"ID":"aaa","time_CET":"00:45:00", "VAL": 225}, ->0.9*250

    {"ID":"bbb","time_CET":"00:00:00", "VAL": 175}, ->0.5*350
    {"ID":"bbb","time_CET":"00:15:00", "VAL": 245}, ->0.7*350
    {"ID":"bbb","time_CET":"00:30:00", "VAL": 280}, ->0.8*350
    {"ID":"bbb","time_CET":"00:45:00", "VAL": 315}, ->0.9*350

    {"ID":"ccc","time_CET":"00:00:00", "VAL": 100}, ->0.5*200
    {"ID":"ccc","time_CET":"00:15:00", "VAL": 140}, ->0.7*200
    {"ID":"ccc","time_CET":"00:30:00", "VAL": 160}, ->0.8*200
    {"ID":"ccc","time_CET":"00:45:00", "VAL": 180}, ->0.9*200

    {"ID":"ddd","time_CET":"00:00:00", "VAL": 95}, ->0.5*190
    {"ID":"ddd","time_CET":"00:15:00", "VAL": 133}, ->0.7*190
    {"ID":"ddd","time_CET":"00:30:00", "VAL": 152}, ->0.8*190
    {"ID":"ddd","time_CET":"00:45:00", "VAL": 171}, ->0.9*190
  ]
  ```

So I am not sure if that is even possible. Perhaps I have to reshape the ratio array to objects? (objects with "time_cet" key and not an array of values).

Anyway, what is the best way to accomplish this with jq (and maybe linux bash)?  Thank you!

UPDATE: Both solutions work now, thank you very much. 
This is maybe another topic but I would like to add an error handler to catch exceptions especially for the RATIO array. 
It may happen that this Array

1.Does not contain a value at the specified index/not definded

2.Value that is not an integer

In any case I would like to set a default value for VAL. The error message should be logged in another file, if that is possible.. (can I use the current date here? -> maybe send to STDERR?) Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following jq program is in a file, say program.jq, then the invocation:

```
jq --argfile ratio ratio.json --argfile constants constants.json  -f program.jq data.json
```

produces the desired result, at least if jq 1.5 or later is used:

```
# r should be an array of ratios
# input is assumed to be an object with .time_CET
def getRatio(r):
  if .time_CET=="00:00:00" then r[0]
  elif  .time_CET=="00:15:00" then r[1]
  elif  .time_CET=="00:30:00" then r[2]
  else r[3]
  end
  ;

def todict: reduce .[] as $o ({}; . + ($o | { (.ID): .CONST }));

def extend(r):
  ($constants|todict)[.ID]  as $c
  | .VAL = getRatio(r) * $c
  ;

($ratio[0] | .RATIO) as $RATIO
| map(extend($RATIO))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I get the following error:  
jq:error (at data.json:21): number(0.5) and null (null) cannot be multiplied.   hmm.. Where comes this null from? Yes, I use jq-1.5.

Comment: For testing, I used this for ratio.json: [
 {"a": "...","RATIO":[0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9], "c": "...."}
]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
# recent versions of jq include this in builtin.jq.
# we redefine it here in case it's not present
def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
  reduce stream as $row (
    {}
  ; .[$row|idx_expr|if type != "string" then tojson else . end] |= $row
  )
;

# make an array of all the times that appear in time_CET
def datatimes:
   [$data[].time_CET] | unique[]
;

# make an object mapping time_CET to ratios
def time_to_ratio:
    reduce datatimes as $i (
      {}
    ; .[$i] = $ratio[0].RATIO[length]
    )
;

# main procedure here

  INDEX($constants[];.ID) as $ctable
| time_to_ratio as $rtable
| $data
| map(.VAL = $ctable[.ID].CONST * $rtable[.time_CET])
```

if this filter is in `filter.jq` and the other data is in the `constants.json`, `ratio.json` and `data.json` files respectively then the command

```
jq -Mnc \
   --argfile constants constants.json \
   --argfile data data.json \
   --argfile ratio ratio.json \
   -f filter.jq
```

produces

```
[
  {
    "ID": "aaa",
    "time_CET": "00:00:00",
    "VAL": 125
  },
  {
    "ID": "aaa",
    "time_CET": "00:15:00",
    "VAL": 175
  },
  {
    "ID": "aaa",
    "time_CET": "00:30:00",
    "VAL": 200
  },
  {
    "ID": "aaa",
    "time_CET": "00:45:00",
    "VAL": 225
  },
  {
    "ID": "bbb",
    "time_CET": "00:00:00",
    "VAL": 175
  },
  {
    "ID": "bbb",
    "time_CET": "00:15:00",
    "VAL": 244.99999999999997
  },
  {
    "ID": "bbb",
    "time_CET": "00:30:00",
    "VAL": 280
  },
  {
    "ID": "bbb",
    "time_CET": "00:45:00",
    "VAL": 315
  },
  {
    "ID": "ccc",
    "time_CET": "00:00:00",
    "VAL": 100
  },
  {
    "ID": "ccc",
    "time_CET": "00:15:00",
    "VAL": 140
  },
  {
    "ID": "ccc",
    "time_CET": "00:30:00",
    "VAL": 160
  },
  {
    "ID": "ccc",
    "time_CET": "00:45:00",
    "VAL": 180
  },
  {
    "ID": "ddd",
    "time_CET": "00:00:00",
    "VAL": 95
  },
  {
    "ID": "ddd",
    "time_CET": "00:15:00",
    "VAL": 133
  },
  {
    "ID": "ddd",
    "time_CET": "00:30:00",
    "VAL": 152
  },
  {
    "ID": "ddd",
    "time_CET": "00:45:00",
    "VAL": 171
  }
]
```

Comment: strange, I also got a similar error with your solution, what can that be?:      
 jq: error (at <unknow>): null(null) and number (0.5) cannot be multiplied

Comment: There is only one multiplication in my answer: `map(.VAL = $ctable[.ID].CONST * $rtable[.time_CET])`.  The 0.5 is probably a ratio so the problem may be that constants.json is missing an element for some ID.

Comment: Perhaps you could update the question to specify how missing or irregular data should be handled?

Comment: Thanks it works now! It was my fault. However, an error handler would still be nice.